# php CURL Error: Request payload is not JSON

Tags: php, json, curl, post, request

I am trying to interact with an Api using php's CURL library

this is my code:

```
$fields = array(
    'aaaaa' => 'aaaaa', 
    'bbbbb' => 'bbbbb', 
    'ccccc' => 'ccccc', 
    'ddddd' => 'ddddd'
);

$fields_json = json_encode($fields);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->api_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_json);

// var_dump($fields_json);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type" => "application/json"
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

since the function returned NULL, I tried to `var_dump` the variable `$result` and this is what i got:

```
array(1) { ["message"]=> string(27) "Request payload is not JSON" }
```

I tried searching for solutions but every page I've seen said that this is the correct way, what am I missing?

Thank You!

**(17/01/2024 11:00:00) EDIT:**

I've also tried to make the same request with ThunderClient extension for VSCode, same url, same body and it works fine

Comment: This sounds very bizarre. It certainly appears that you are sending JSON correctly. Are you able to speak to the maintainers of this API?

Comment: @ADyson yes, my company hosts it, but doesn't it look like CURL itself is giving this error? (to me it looks like curl was trying to send the request and then stopped 'cause the body isn't a JSON)

Comment: Curl sent the request no problem. The error message looks like it is in the response you are getting back from the API server. For some reason it doesn't like what you sent. Have you tried sending the same request to this API from a tool like PostMan? That would help you to identify whether your code or the remote server which is at fault.

Comment: @ADyson I just tried making the request with ThunderClient for VSCode
same url, same body, and it works perfectly fine :(

Comment: You're passing the header in the wrong format. Quote PHP docs on curl_setopt: _"CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER: An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @CBroe:

> You're passing the header in the wrong format. Quote PHP docs on curl_setopt: "CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER: An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')"

This is the code i fixed:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    ));
```